# Can you create Outlook Calendar Groups from local calendars?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

When I do "Create New Calendar Group", it seems that I can only add Exchange calendars. Is there a way to add local calendars?

I have multiple local calendars, and I want to have use Calendar Groups as "presets" instead of toggling the show/hide calendars each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can you create Outlook Calendar Groups from local calendars?

Not sure what you mean by "local calendars" exactly, but Calendar Groups are actually a feature of Exchange Server, not Outlook (it can just display/modify them, as a client)

So it will only work with Exchange-based email accounts.

From [Create, view, or delete a calendar group](https://support.office.com/en-sg/article/Create-view-or-delete-a-calendar-group-04fc64f2-b658-450b-8dce-dd27ed660570):

> Note: This feature requires a Microsoft Exchange Server account.

From [Outlook group calendar solutions](http://www.outlookipedia.com/outlook/group-calendar.aspx):

> This feature requires you to use a Microsoft Exchange Server [...] account. Most home and personal accounts do not use Microsoft Exchange.

Comment: Thanks, that answered my question. By "local calendars" I meant non-Exchange calendars that reside on my local computer only.